# How to send emails from Gmail without turning on "allow less secure apps" setting?

Tags: django, email, smtp, gmail

Is there any way to send an email in a Django project without turning on the "allow less secure apps" feature? Is using OAuth2 a must or can I send it using Google's API?

So far, I just use:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemailaddress'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

But this gives me an SMTPAuthenticationError, which only works when I turn on "allow less secure apps" in Google.  Is there any way to circumvent this without using OAuth2 and allow multiple users to login to that account easily?

Answer (score 2):

> Using the `gmail app password` through you can send the email not provide the actual password and no one can login in your account. Without enable less secure apps setting  here is give the link try and it's work let me know if it right [google or gmail app password](https://support.teamgate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002064229-How-to-create-a-password-to-connect-email-while-using-2-step-verification-in-Gmail-)

after it change the actual password to your app password in

`setting.py` file `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your app password'`  give by google
not change in other constant

> if you do not use 2 step email verification you need to use third party service here i give the link you see [sendgrid](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/13/how-to-send-email.html)

Comment: If I use two step verification, how can I allow a different coworker to access that same email address?

Comment: if you use two step verification no one login that password in your gmail but if you use in development it send email so you need to use the third party service i update my answer pls read